# Python -- Go back to an input variable in while loop (NOT beginning of the loop)

Tags: while-loop

I'm a beginner struggling with the logic/structure of my code.

I'm trying to code a virtual tour that allows the user to walk from one room to another in a house (just the hard code).

I start in the living room and I'm able to go to the rooms that are linked to the living room and come back.

Example: go outside, come back to the living room.

After that, I can't go back outside unless I copy and paste the input for outside under the living room input again.

Does that make sense? How can I go back to a certain input variable without having to copy and paste it again and again and end up in a never ending loop?

PS:not done with all the rooms

```
while True:
    living_room = input("""
You are in the living room. There's a 55 inch TV, 2 sofas and a center table.
Options: Outside/ Kitchen/ Hallway
> """).lower()
    if living_room == "outside":
        outside = input("""
You are outside. It's a cloudy day and your house is located in a very quiet street, so, no cars are passing by.
Options: Living room/ Garage
> """).lower()
        if outside == "living room":
            living_room = input("""
You are in the living room. There's a 55 inch TV, 2 sofas and a center table.
Options: Outside/ Kitchen/ Hallway
> """).lower()
        if outside == "garage":
            garage = input("""
            You are in the garage. There's a lot of junk in here, and your car is parked on the driveway.
            Options: Kitchen/ Outside
            > """).lower()
    elif living_room == "kitchen":
        kitchen = input("""
You are in the kitchen. There's a dinning table with 6 chairs, a refrigerator, stove, microwave, counter and sink.
Options: Living room/ Garage/ Backyard
> """).lower()
    elif living_room == "hallway":
        hallway = input("""
You are in the Hallway. 
Options: Living room/ Bathroom 1/ Bedroom 1/ Bedroom 2/ Bedroom 3
> """).lower()
```

Comment: You're going to want to refactor this. In the simplest sense, if you want to return to some code that was executed previously, that code should be at the top of a loop. You may want to generalize the code you have by having a function that handles navigation between rooms. Then you give that function the options that the user has for it to present to the user. On top of that, if you want a history of where the user went, maintain a stack of room names by pushing to the stack when they ether a room, the pop from the stack to get the name of the last visited room.

Comment: In short, there isn't any literal way to do what you want. You'd need a `goto`, but that wouldn't be a good idea anyways, even if the language supported such a construct.